# Execution time and process time fluctuation

Tags: java, profiling, cpu, profiler, cpu-usage

Why there is fluctuation in execution and process CPU time vary every time i run the below code in Netbeans. Does my CPU usage also vary every time. And how do I find CPU usage for the below code.

```
class test{
static com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean mxbean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long pstart1 = mxbean.getProcessCpuTime();
        long pstart2 = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(pstart1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);        

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {    

            System.out.println("hello");

    }     

        long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long pend1 = mxbean.getProcessCpuTime();
        long pend2 = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(pend1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        float pdif = pend2 - pstart2;
        float edif = end1 - start1;

        System.out.println(edif);
        System.out.println(pdif);

}
}
```

Comment: Yes it may vary, depending on the availability of CPU to jvm

Comment: Then how to determine the exact execution time and cpu time

Comment: There are profilers available to measure. and generally you measure the average result of n try

Answer (score 1):

You are performing mostly IO so you as very dependant on the behaviour of the OS.

Millis-seconds is not very accurate and can have resolutions of more than 1 ms. e.g. currentTimeMillis has a resolution of about 15 ms on Windows XP.  The cpu time used has a resolution of 10 ms on many unix systems.

If you make the task CPU bound instead of IO bound and run it for longer you should see more consistent timings.

Comment: The method you are using are the best available for this.  Given you have a short lived IO bound task the CPU is unlikely to tell you much. In a more realistic example, you might be useful.